# php built-in webserver errors log (Zend Framework 2 App)

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I use php built-in webserver to debug locally my websites.

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

Sometimes if something is wrong I have a generic 500 error in stdout and I don't understand where is the problem.

```
 127.0.0.1:51936 [500]: /dashboard
```

Is there a method to have a more descriptive error like the error.log?

EDIT:

My error was

```
$this->userDisplayName()
```

instead of

```
$this->zfcUserDisplayName()
```

In a PHTML view in my Zend Framework 2 App

Comment: switch on `display_errors` and `error_reporting` in your PHP.ini file, and you should get the errors showing up in the browser.

Comment: I tried this but doesn't worked.

My error was
$this->userDisplayName()

instead of 

$this->zfcUserDisplayName()

in a phtml view in my zend framework 2 app 

I don't know why PHP didn't show the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

This was a bug of the current Zend Framework stable version (`2.0.6`)

I have updated my project to developer branch (`dev-master`) and now it work correctly. I have a correct stacktrace for each error.

Link to the issue:
https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/2991

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

I honestly haven't worked with the php built-in feature yet, so I have no experience and nuch much clue but... in apache you set your `LogLevel` directive to `debug`... so how about trying these settings in `php.ini`

```
display_errors: On
error_reporting: E_ALL
log_errors: On
```